# Getting Redirect issue on codeigniter website

Tags: redirect

when i search website on sometime is load sometime it redirect to unknown links how to fix it. website design on codeigniter.
i have checked, htaccess file, recover with backup file but getting same error please help me regarding this error.
Ibhave tried to recover backup but getting same issue.